# Caching file pointers in C

Tags: c, caching, thread-safety, file-pointer

I need to cache file pointers in my program, but the problem is that I may have multiple threads accessing that file pointer cache. For example, if thread1 asks for a file pointer, and a cache miss occurs, fopen is called and the pointer is cached. Now when thread 2 arrives and cache hit occurs, both the files share the read/write pointer leading to errors. Some things I thought of -

- I could keep track of when the file is in use, but currently I don't know when it will be released, and including this feature disturbs my design
- I could send a duplicate of the file pointer in case of a hit, but I don't know any way of doing this so that these two copies do not share read/write locations

How should I proceed?

Comment: Why do you need to cache?

Comment: Perhaps each thread should have it's own cache ?

Comment: Use `TLS` as @SteveP mentioned. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage

Comment: @DarkFalcon, I don't want to call fopen again and again, I suppose it would be expensive

Comment: @SteveP Basically it is a client server program and the server caches the file pointers for all the clients, if it were maintaining a cache for each client separately I think the overhead might be more than caching benefit

Comment: But each client needs it's own read/write location, so there is nothing shared between them to cache.

Comment: This isn't clear; you want a cache to allow you to share file handles, but you also don't want multiple threads to use the same file handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you concerned about optimizing out the file open operation? I think you are making it way more complex and error prone than what it should be. File pointers (`FILE*`) are not thread-safe structures so you cannot share them across threads.

What you probably need to do (if you *really* want to cache the file open operations) is to keep a dictionary mapping filename to a file *descriptor* (an `int`) and have a thread-safe function to return a descriptor by name or open if it's not in the dictionary.

And of course doing I/O to the same file descriptor from multiple threads needs to be regulated as well.